# How to force jQuery dialog to wait for response

Tags: jquery, email, jquery-ui-dialog

I want a user to confirm, via a jQuery UI dialog box, that he or she accepts or rejects certain terms when a mailto link is clicked. When I use the following code, the dialog box briefly appears, but then automatically closes as the page is redirected to the default email program.

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    .html('Do you accept these terms?')
    .dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title: 'Disclaimer',
        resizable: false,
        width: 500,
        modal: true,
        buttons:            
            {
    "Accept": function() {
      $( this ).dialog( "close" );},
    "Reject": function() {
      $( this ).dialog( "close" ); }
 }
 });

$('.email-address').click(function() {
    $dialog.dialog('open');

});
});
```

HTML:

```
<a class="email-address" href="mailto:'info@example.com">info@example.com</a>
```

Any suggestions on the best way to require a response before the dialog box can be closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would remove the href="mailto" from the html, set it to # and run the mailto from inside your function.

HTML:

```
<a class="email-address" href="#">info@example.com</a>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
  .html('Do you accept these terms?')
  .dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    title: 'Disclaimer',
    resizable: false,
    width: 500,
    modal: true,
    buttons:{
      "Accept": function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        window.location.href = "mailto:info@example.com";
      },
      "Reject": function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" ); }
      }
   });

  $('.email-address').click(function() {
    $dialog.dialog('open');

  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because of the default action of the link you are clicking, you need to prevent the default action of the link and on accept you need to redirect the user to the page